# download images from a webpage that loads other images on scrolldown

Tags: python, web-scraping

there are sites such as https://unsplash.com/t/nature which load other images after scrolling down the page, in python what is the best way to download all the images from this link, including those that load when do you scroll down the page? Can you give me examples?

Comment: You probably need to run javascripts in the page. This link might be helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-skills-web-scraping-javascript-using-python-97a29738353f

Comment: if page use JavaScript then you may need to use `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript. OR using DevTool in Chrome/Firefox you can try to find what url is used by JavaScript to load new data and then you can try to use this url to get new data without Selenium. It should work fater because it doesn't need to run web browser and wait till it loads new data.

Comment: I just found a little shortcut, after inspecting network tab on google chrome I notice that every time I scroll down the page a link is load with this form https://www.mywebsite.com/otherthings/limit=20&offset=20. So I just take all the images from this url, then increase the offset and download again new images